# Use javascript to fetch content from external site

Tags: javascript, external, fetch

Say I there's mypage.html and otherpage.html

otherpage.html has some content `<p>content is content</p>`

I want a javascript that can fetch the content from otherpage.html and paste it in mypage.html

Is there a javascript that can accomplish this? thanks.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX and HTML parsing.  It's trivial with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

From the title, it appears that otherpage.html is in a different domain. This being the case this is not possible in the browser (there's a few exceptions with flash/java/silverlight). If the page is in the same domain, it's easy. Take a look at [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: I think it is useful to at least provide a link to explain the same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy